# Update data table keeping filters and sort

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using [ng2-smart-table](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table) I'm updating the information with a  `setInterval` function every 2 mins I receive new information.

The **issue** is when I'm filtering, sorting or using the pagination of the data table the interval is triggered and the data table return to default filter and sort etc.

I'm looking for some way to update `pendingAlerts` but without affecting the current filter or sort in the data table. I'm thinking in affecting directly every instance of the array but I don't  know if it is a good approach.

**HTML**

```
<ng2-smart-table (userRowSelect)="onRowSelected($event)" [settings]="settings" [source]="pendingAlerts"></ng2-smart-table>
```

I'm using an storedata with a observable  pattern to retrieve the information I think that isn't relevant to show this code

**Component**

```
...
pendingAlerts: Pending[] =[];
...
next = (data: Pending[]) => {
    console.log("Receiving info from observer"+ data.length);
    this.pendingAlerts = data;   

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is by using `LocalDataSource` class and `load` function to load data. and you will keep your filter and sorting configuration.

**Component**

```
pendingAlerts: LocalDataSource;
count: number = 0;
ngOnInit() {    
  this.pendingAlerts = new LocalDataSource([]); 
  this.pendingAlerts.onChanged().subscribe(res =>{
      this.count = this.pendingAlerts.count();
  });  
}

  next = (data: Pending[]) => {
    console.log("Receiving info from observer"+ data.length);
    this.pendingAlerts.load(data);   

  }
```